# Reproduce "A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server."

Tags: c#

We're using WebClient, .NET 3.5sp1 in a winforms application. For some users this results
in an Exception with the message:

"The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server."

Searching a bit around the web suggests a "fix" to just disable http keepalive, which we're not really interested in doing, some suggests it might be a bug in the .NET libraries, etc.

The error message suggests it's a keepaliv'ed http connection that somehow got closed by the server(or a proxy) without the underlyings of WebClient detecting it properly.

We're thinking of catching this specific case, and simply try the request again. However we cannot reproduce this exception. So.

1. How can we properly catch the case that yields the above error message.

   catch(WebException ex) {
       if (ex.Message == "The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server") { ... }

   smells.. bad.
2. Any tips on how we can reproduce the above exception ?

Comment: `For some users` suggests that it's not everyone. Are those users behind a proxy (either explicitly set, or a transparent proxy)? Busy proxy servers in corporate environments may drop connections unexpectedly, hence the exception. Either way, it's a network problem (client, host, or the intermediary bits) of some sort, not a bug in the .NET Framework.

Comment: You're probably right that it's a network problem. Thus we want to try to simply retry the request if this particular, though all we know is this text that's originated from a WebException - so is there a reliably way to detect this specific excception, some specific error code or what not ? And we want to reproduce it, so we can test that retrying the request doesn't cause some other badness when "connection was closed" has occured

Comment: I am getting the same error when I am trying to send large data from the service layer. Any clue why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

WebClient detects this just fine.  Thus the exception.  You need to find the server that's misbehaving.  Not quite sure what to do if you find that server, maybe you can send the admin a nice email message.

Log the server URL.

Comment: Well, this could be anything from an overloaded nat gateway closing the connection prematurely, to a proxy server inbetween acting up, none of which anyone will ever figure out let alone fix. In the mean time it's the users that suffer. Here's also an obvious race condition - e.g. what if the server correctly send a Connection-Close: while the client is trying to send a new request on the cached connection, but the connection-close havn't been received yet. Thus the question - any neat way we can reproduce this exception, and how do we check for this particular case bar comparing e.Message ?

Comment: Customizing the exception handling is only useful if you can do something in your code to fix the problem.  You cannot fix an overloaded router or a balky server.  And the operating system can't tell the difference.  This belongs to a large category of WebExceptions, you can only try again, later.  Which is why there's no dedicated exception class for this failure.  Similar to IOException ("crap happened") vs FileNotFoundException ("common crap, might be able to fix that").

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/01/07/you-receive-one-or-more-error-messages-when-you-try-to-make-an-http-request-in-an-application-that-is-built-on-the-net-framework-2-0.aspx) blog by Misrosoft: Http Client Protocol Issues